# Celery task re-queued into broker on graceful shutdown when run locally but get lost in kubernetes despite same configs

Tags: django-celery, kubernetes-pod, celery-task, sigterm, graceful-shutdown

I have a celery running in k8 pod. This is my manifest for celery

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: celery
  labels:
    deployment: celery
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: celery
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: celery
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: celery
          image: local_celery:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          command: ['celery', '-A', 'proj', 'worker', '-E', '-l', 'info',]
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
            requests:
              cpu: 50m

      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 25
```

My Celery Configs in django settings.py are

```
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY=1
CEELERY_TASK_REJECT_ON_WORKER_LOST=True
```

When I run a simple django app with celery and redis as message broker, My task get re-queued into broker when i do `ctrl-C` to initiate a warm shutdown for the worker. But when the same application is deployed to kubernetes with celery, django and redis running in 3 different pods
my tasks aren't re-queued back to redis when celery pod is gracefully terminated. I am unable to understand why? My celery settings are unchanged in both cases.

Comment: Hi @sap, what was you finding on this? how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your celery worker is being shutdown gracefully on kubernetes?

It is not mentioned enough when they say k8s sends `SIGTERM` signal on pod/container when it is terminating and `SIGKILL` after `terminationgraceperiod` if the pod is still there, that, k8s sends that SIGTERM to process id no 1 (`PID 1`). So if your main celery worker process is not `PID 1` the graceful shutdown will not happen. this happens if you are not running the actual celery command inline and run through from script file with sh/bash.

also we must implement signal handler when running process in pid1. celery in our case has obviously has that. [read more](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-building-containers)